# How to databind a Slider to Viewmodel property in Xamarin forms?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-mac

I'm new to Xamarin forms and have only been working with it for a few months.  I have a Xamarin forms app that will be used with Android and iOS and is using the MVVM structure. I have an `ObservableCollection` of objects in my ViewModel that I am iterating over with a custom repeater view that extends `StackLayout` and inside of the `DataTemplate` I have a custom Entry class that extends Entry that is binding its `Text` attribute to the object's `Value` property (a nullable double).

What I want to do next, is modify the template to hide the `Entry` tag if a certain boolean that I am adding into the model has a value of true, and then display a `Slider` and a `Label`, to show the value of the `Slider`.

So far I have been able to bind the `Maximum`/`Minimum` attributes to properties from my Viewmodel which is great, but whenever I try to bind the `Value` property to the `Slider`, my XAML won't load up, and I'm not getting any error. I also will need to implement functionality to only allow the user to slide over a given 'increment' (.1, 1, 2, etc).  I would like to slide the `Slider` and once the user stops sliding, the `Value` property is set and stored in the model.  I also need to it to pre-load if there is a value already existing, but those two I can get to later.

I think I am going about this incorrectly. I have tried searching through lots of different examples but I cannot for the life of me figure this out.

Here is what my XAML looks like for the slider/label

```
<Slider x:Name="slider" Value="{Binding Value}"
          Maximum="{Binding VM.Question.NumericMaxValue}"/>
   <Label x:Name="displayLabel"  
          Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference slider},  Path=Value,
          StringFormat='The slider value is {0:F0}'}" 
          HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
```

A simplified version of my Model because I don't want to put code out there that I maybe shouldn't.

```
public class MyItemModel
{
    private double? _value;

 public double? Value
   {
       get { return _value; }
       set
       {
           if (_value != value)
           {
               _value = value;


               if (!FormatAsTime)
               {
                   if (VM.Question.NumericMaxValue != -1 && Value > VM.Question.NumericMaxValue)
                   {
                       Value = VM.Question.NumericMaxValue;
                       return;
                   }
                   if (Value < VM.Question.NumericMinValue)
                   {
                       Value = VM.Question.NumericMinValue;
                       return;
                   }

                   RaisePropertyChanged(() => Value);
                   RaisePropertyChanged(() => HasValue);

                   SpinDownCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
                   SpinUpCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
               }
               else
               {
                   RaisePropertyChanged(() => Value);
                   RaisePropertyChanged(() => HasValue);
               }

               VM.UpdateCanGoNext();
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Slider's Value is a double, your VM is a nullable double

Comment: Check the debug output for binding errors

Comment: @Jason you were correct, I changed the binding to a different double property and it is working now.  In the Set method for my new property i just call to the original Value property and assign it the value.   I still need to implement increments though and I'm not sure if that is possible.  Do you have any advice there?

Comment: Slider doesn't support increments.  You would need to write your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code you put (there are some missing key parts),
but I presume you should use **`TwoWay`** binding:

```
<Slider x:Name="slider" 
    Value="{Binding Value, Mode=TwoWay}"
    Maximum="{Binding VM.Question.NumericMaxValue}"
    />
```

You also don't need to use a `Nullable<double>` for your property (as @jason mentionned it) because the slider control has always a value.

And why your second binding (`Maximum` property) is equal to '`VM.Question`...' ?
Is it not the same for the `Value` binding ? 
ie:

```
Value="{Binding VM.Value, Mode=TwoWay}" -- ??
```

---

To update the value only when the control's thumb has finished to "move", you should use reactive extensions.
It allow to you to manipulate events and select the "last" one of a serie for instance:

[Rx for Xamarin forms presentation](https://xamarinhelp.com/introduction-reactive-extensions-rx-net/)

I let you see and check for more details...

Comment: The reason the bindings are different is because I am iterating over the Collection of 'QuestionItems' that are contained within the 'VM.Question' object.  That same object holds my 'Min' and 'Max' value, hope that makes sense.


I will take a look at the reactive extensions, thank you.  


Do you have any advice for implementing an 'interval' for the slider??  I need to be able to modify so that the user can slide through certain increments (like a tenth of a point).  ie: 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, etc.

Comment: I hope I understand well, but to simulate an interval, you can implement a converter (that you will set into  your 'Value' binding). In this converter you can "round" the input value to your interval value... ie: 0.12 => 0.0 / 0.74 => 1.0 (doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/converters)

Comment: Okay that is what i had in mind @KFactory.  I don't really understand you example though.  what is the interval there?  .12?

Comment: Nevermind, It was just an example... I just want to say, if the value is 0.12 then round it to 0 ...